# What's the difference between android:permission="packagename.permissions.BROWSER_PROVIDER" and android:grantUriPermissions?

Tags: android

I am curious simply because the uri I am trying to access says the following:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.foo.MyProvider uri content://com.foo/history from pid=20735, uid=10080 requires com.foo.permissions.BROWSER_PROVIDER, or grantUriPermission()
```

However, the provider within that app actually has:

```
<provider android:name="com.foo.MyProvider"
          android:authorities="com.foo.db.mydb"
          android:permission="com.foo.permissions.BROWSER_PROVIDER">=
</provider>
```

Does this mean that I actually DO need the `android:grantUriPermissions=true` on the provider as well? What is the difference between these two declarations?

---

EXAMPLE:

Here is a provider which I am going to attempt to access from within my own application:

http://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/mobile/android/base/AndroidManifest.xml.in#274

If I were to attempt to register an observer to that provider's uri (which happens to be `content://org.mozilla.firefox.db.browser/history`) with the following code:

```
    private ContentObserver mFirefoxObserver;
    resolver.registerContentObserver("content://org.mozilla.firefox.db.browser/history", true, mFirefoxObserver);
```

Then the error received is:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading org.mozilla.gecko.db.BrowserProvider uri content://org.mozilla.firefox.db.browser/history from pid=20735, uid=10080 requires org.mozilla.firefox.permissions.BROWSER_PROVIDER, or grantUriPermission()
```

But, you'll notice that the permission IS set in the provider:

```
<provider android:name="org.mozilla.gecko.db.BrowserProvider"
              android:authorities="@ANDROID_PACKAGE_NAME@.db.browser"
              android:permission="@ANDROID_PACKAGE_NAME@.permissions.BROWSER_PROVIDER">
...
```

So my question is, why does the error say I need that permission OR grantUriPermissions, when one is clearly there?

Comment: Can you post the rest of your manifest? If you're not declaring that your app uses that permission, you won't have access. `android:grantUriPermissions` is mostly for one-time access type scenarios.

Comment: http://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/mobile/android/base/AndroidManifest.xml.in#274

Comment: I'm confused by that link. If it's your provider, then you don't need `android:grantUriPermissions` as you can just grant yourself the required permission. If it's someone else's provider, you need to use their permission. Or, if they have `android:grantUriPermissions` set to true, you can request permission in the Intent. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html

Comment: Its not my provider. Please read the updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at this [line](http://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/mobile/android/base/AndroidManifest.xml.in#329), you'll see the declaration of this permission

```
<permission android:name="@ANDROID_PACKAGE_NAME@.permissions.BROWSER_PROVIDER"
            android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
```

Since this is a signature level permission, you cannot hold this permission. Only apps signed with the same developer key as that app can.

Back to the provider now, here is it's full declaration:

```
<provider android:name="org.mozilla.gecko.db.BrowserProvider"
          android:authorities="@ANDROID_PACKAGE_NAME@.db.browser"
          android:permission="@ANDROID_PACKAGE_NAME@.permissions.BROWSER_PROVIDER">

        <path-permission android:pathPrefix="/search_suggest_query"
                         android:readPermission="android.permission.GLOBAL_SEARCH" />

</provider>
```

Here it says that you need `org.mozilla.firefox.permissions.BROWSER_PROVIDER` to access the provider outright, which as I pointed out above, you cannot have. Within the provider though is the key part, [`<path-permission>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/path-permission-element.html). What this element is saying is that you can access paths beginning with `/search_suggest_query` if you hold the `android.permission.GLOBAL_SEARCH` permission.

You're getting a security exception because you are trying to access `/history`, which you are not allowed to do.

Comment: This answers me perfectly.

Now, lets just say the owner of the provider wishes to allow my app to access the provider -- and only my app -- is this possible?

Comment: I'm not sure how (or if) that would be possible. You might want to open a new question for that.

Comment: Same. I shall do that.