# Security issues when using Content Provider in BluetoothGattCallback

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am observing a strange permission related issue when onCharacteristicChanged() callback is called.

I am writing an Android service that communicates with LE (Low Energy) sensor in peripheral role using Bluetooth LE APIs. I enable notification on a characteristic on which sensor notifies any changes.

When onCharacteristicChanged() callback is called, my service retrieves characteristic's value and stores it in a content provider. Access to this content provider is restricted by signature level permission. Application hosting my service has those permission.

Here is the simplified code of onCharacteristicChanged:

```
@Override
public void onCharacteristicChanged(final BluetoothGatt gatt, final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic);

    Log.v(TAG, "pid=" + android.os.Process.myPid() + " uid=" + android.os.Process.myUid());

    Uri uri = mContext.getContentResolver().insert(URI_VALUES, characteristic.getValue());
}
```

I am getting a security permission when insert() api is called in the above callback.

```
02-27 15:15:32.752: V/ProxyGattClient(10511): pid=10511 uid=10177
02-27 15:15:32.792: E/PersistenceUtil(10511): Error saving a reading into the database
02-27 15:15:32.792: E/PersistenceUtil(10511): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.example.content.MyContentProvider uri content://com.example/values from pid=1336, uid=1002 requires com.example.permission.ACCESS_CONTENT, or grantUriPermission()
02-27 15:15:32.792: E/PersistenceUtil(10511):   at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceWritePermissionInner(ContentProvider.java:445)
02-27 15:15:32.792: E/PersistenceUtil(10511):   at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceWritePermission(ContentProvider.java:382)
02-27 15:15:32.792: E/PersistenceUtil(10511):   at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.insert(ContentProvider.java:210)
02-27 15:15:32.792: E/PersistenceUtil(10511):   at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:917)
02-27 15:15:32.792: E/PersistenceUtil(10511):   at com.qcl.vh.ble.ProxyGattClient.onCharacteristicChanged(ProxyGattClient.java:101)
02-27 15:15:32.792: E/PersistenceUtil(10511):   at android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt$1.onNotify(BluetoothGatt.java:425)
02-27 15:15:32.792: E/PersistenceUtil(10511):   at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGattCallback$Stub.onTransact(IBluetoothGattCallback.java:397)
02-27 15:15:32.792: E/PersistenceUtil(10511):   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
02-27 15:15:32.792: E/PersistenceUtil(10511):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Running 'adb shell ps' shows pid=1336, uid=1002 is the process id of "com.android.bluetooth" process. Above stack trace shows, that content provider's insert is being called in bluetooth process's context. Of course this process does not have permission to write in content provider and thus this exception.

When I log process's id within onCharacteristicChanged() it shows pid=10511 uid=10177, which is the process id of the process that is hosting my application.

Can someone explain that above behavior? Why insert() is called on blueooth process's context while the callback itself is running in my application's process.

I am running on Samsung Galaxy S3, Android 4.3.

thanks

Comment: signature permission means that they must both be signed by the same application developer key.... which isn't possible for the System bluetooth?

Comment: I had the same problem and resorted to calling a Service from BluetoothGattCallback.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is right in your error, I believe.

`requires com.example.permission.ACCESS_CONTENT`

You must allow others to read from your contentProvider. Read more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/grant-uri-permission-element.html)

Could you show how you know that the host application has these permissions? I've asked a very similar question in the past, here:

[What's the difference between android:permission="packagename.permissions.BROWSER_PROVIDER" and android:grantUriPermissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21947266/whats-the-difference-between-androidpermission-packagename-permissions-browse)

Comment: Here are related declarations in manifest

<permission android:name="com.example.permission.ACCESS_CONTENT" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
  
<provider android:name="com.example.content.MyProvider"
    android:authorities="com.example"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="com.example.permission.ACCESS_CONTENT">
</provider>